# Pseudo selector:checked not showing preceding div

Tags: html, css

```css
  *{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   font-family:verdana;
   font-size:17px;
   color:white;
  }
  #main{
   
   display:flex;
   background-color:#aaa;
  }
  #parent-ul{
   display:inline-flex;
   justify-content:flex-end;
   list-style-type:none;
   background-color:#aaa;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   
  }

  #parent-ul li a{
   
   text-decoration:none;
  }

  .logo{
   display:inline-flex; 
   margin-right:auto;
   margin-left:20px;
   margin-top:20px;
   margin-bottom:20px;
   color:white;
  }
  .nav-items{
   margin-right:20px;
   margin-top:20px;
   margin-bottom:20px;
   flex-shrink:1;
   flex-grow:0;
  }
  .nav-checkbox{
   display:none;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width:460px){
  .nav-checkbox{
   display:block;
   margin-top:30px;
  }
  nav{
   display:none;
  }


  input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ nav{
   display:block;
   background-color:red;
   position: absolute;
     }
```

```css
  *{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   font-family:verdana;
   font-size:17px;
   color:white;
  }
  #main{
   
   display:flex;
   background-color:#aaa;
  }
  #parent-ul{
   display:inline-flex;
   justify-content:flex-end;
   list-style-type:none;
   background-color:#aaa;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   
  }

  #parent-ul li a{
   
   text-decoration:none;
  }

  .logo{
   display:inline-flex; 
   margin-right:auto;
   margin-left:20px;
   margin-top:20px;
   margin-bottom:20px;
   color:white;
  }
  .nav-items{
   margin-right:20px;
   margin-top:20px;
   margin-bottom:20px;
   flex-shrink:1;
   flex-grow:0;
  }
  .nav-checkbox{
   display:none;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width:460px){
  .nav-checkbox{
   display:block;
   margin-top:30px;
  }
  nav{
   display:none;
  }


  input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ nav{
   display:block;
   background-color:red;
   position: absolute;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href ="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div class="logo"><a href="">Sweets</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="nav-checkbox" id="icon">
<nav>
<ul class="parent-ul" id="parent-ul">
<li class="nav-items"><a href="">Home</li>
<li class="nav-items"><a href="">About-Us</li>
<li class="nav-items"><a href="">Tours</li>
<li class="nav-items"><a href="">Contact-Us</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I checked pseudo element not working it does not show up nav bar elements, am working on responsive navbar with checkbox hack.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you forgot to close your `<a>` tag in `<div class="logo"><a href="">Sweets</div>`, that might fix it ?

Comment: **first You need to add meta tag viewport: inside head tag for media queries**
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgot to close your `<a>` tag.

```
<div class="logo"><a href="">Sweets</a></div>
```

```css
  *{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   font-family:verdana;
   font-size:17px;
   color:white;
  }
  #main{
   
   display:flex;
   background-color:#aaa;
  }
  #parent-ul{
   display:inline-flex;
   justify-content:flex-end;
   list-style-type:none;
   background-color:#aaa;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   
  }

  #parent-ul li a{
   
   text-decoration:none;
  }

  .logo{
   display:inline-flex; 
   margin-right:auto;
   margin-left:20px;
   margin-top:20px;
   margin-bottom:20px;
   color:white;
  }
  .nav-items{
   margin-right:20px;
   margin-top:20px;
   margin-bottom:20px;
   flex-shrink:1;
   flex-grow:0;
  }
  .nav-checkbox{
   display:none;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width:460px){
  .nav-checkbox{
   display:block;
   margin-top:30px;
  }
  nav{
   display:none;
  }


  input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ nav{
   display:block;
   background-color:red;
   position: absolute;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href ="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div class="logo"><a href="">Sweets</a></div>
<input type="checkbox" class="nav-checkbox" id="icon">
<nav>
<ul class="parent-ul" id="parent-ul">
<li class="nav-items"><a href="">Home</li>
<li class="nav-items"><a href="">About-Us</li>
<li class="nav-items"><a href="">Tours</li>
<li class="nav-items"><a href="">Contact-Us</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much buddy